# Conditionally remove rows from data frames

Tags: r, if-statement, filtering

Part of my table looks like this:

| X | Y | Channel | Well |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 123 | 1 | B3 |
| 123 | 123 | 2 | B3 |
| 123 | 123 | 1 | B4 |
| 123 | 123 | 2 | B4 |
| 123 | 123 | 1 | B5 |
| 123 | 123 | 2 | B5 |
| 123 | 123 | 3 | B5 |
| 123 | 123 | 1 | B6 |
| 123 | 123 | 2 | B6 |
| 123 | 123 | 3 | B6 |

What I want to do is to filter out

1. channel no 2 for the well that has only 2 channels
2. channel no 3 that has only 3 channels

For example, for B3 and B4, channel 2 has to be removed, for B5 and B6, channel 3 has to be removed.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the rule is to remove the *N*-th channel in a `Well` that has *N* channels, then the general method is

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Well) %>%
  filter(Channel != n_distinct(Channel)) %>%
  ungroup()

# # A tibble: 6 × 4
#       X     Y Channel Well
#   <int> <int>   <int> <chr>
# 1   123   123       1 B3
# 2   123   123       1 B4
# 3   123   123       1 B5
# 4   123   123       2 B5
# 5   123   123       1 B6   
# 6   123   123       2 B6
```

Comment: Thanks @Darren! This is a good one too!

Answer (score 3):

Here is one option using `tidyverse`, where we create a new helper column to count the number of distinct channels (in case of duplicates). Then, we can specify the 2 conditions in a new column, which will be used to `filter` out the required rows. Then, we can just select the original columns (i.e., `select(names(df))`).

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  group_by(Well) %>%
  mutate(n = n_distinct(Channel),
         remove = case_when(n == 2 & Channel == 2 ~ TRUE,
                            n == 3 & Channel == 3 ~ TRUE,
                            TRUE ~ FALSE)) %>%
  ungroup %>% 
  filter(!remove) %>% 
  select(names(df))
```

**Output**

```
      X     Y Channel Well 
  <int> <int>   <int> <chr>
1   123   123       1 B3   
2   123   123       1 B4   
3   123   123       1 B5   
4   123   123       2 B5   
5   123   123       1 B6   
6   123   123       2 B6
```

Or could be written shorter as:

```
df %>%
  group_by(Well) %>%
  filter(!(n_distinct(Channel) == 2 & Channel == 2) &
           !(n_distinct(Channel) == 3 & Channel == 3)) %>%
  ungroup
```

Or in base R, you could do something like this:

```
agg <- aggregate(data = df, cbind(n = Channel) ~ Well, function(x) n = length(unique(x)))

result <- subset(merge(df, agg, by = "Well", all = TRUE), !(n == 2 & Channel == 2) &
         !(n == 3 & Channel == 3), select = -n)
```

Or if you simply need to remove the last row of each group, then you could just do:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(Well) %>% 
  slice(-n())
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(X = c(123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 
123L, 123L, 123L), Y = c(123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 
123L, 123L, 123L, 123L), Channel = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), Well = c("B3", "B3", "B4", "B4", "B5", "B5", 
"B5", "B6", "B6", "B6")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

Comment: thanks so much for the answers. Adding an column is a smart way to do it!

Comment: @Meifong No problem! I was mostly trying to cover if you had more complicated data. But if you just need to remove the last row for each group (assuming that they are in order), then I've added an update at the bottom. You could just do `df %>% group_by(Well) %>% slice(-n())`.